# Radio Button Check Changed even not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, radio-button

I've 2 radio buttons in a user control and control is registered to the page. When i click on the radio button, the event(CheckChanged) is not firing.

```
<asp:View ID="viewfirst" runat="server">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                        <ContentTemplate>

                            <asp:RadioButton ID="radio1" Text="Yes" Enabled="true" runat="server" />
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="radio2" Text="No" Enabled="true" runat="server" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </asp:View>

Below is code in behind file of the control. 


 Protected Sub radio1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radio1.CheckedChanged
    //
    //
End Sub
```

It seems everything looks good, but something is wrong. Can you please let me know.

Comment: There is nothing in that event, how would you know if it fires or not?

Comment: add `autopostback=true` to radiobutton

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Set **autopostback=true** for checkbox - This will trigger the event
>
> **UpdateMode=conditional** and **ChildrenAsTriggers=false** for the UpdatePanel - so when you trigger checkbox, it won't trigger full postback

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the event handler of each radio button to **OnCheckChanged** and put them in the same **RadioGroup** (GroupName) so they do not fire together. Remember to set **AutoPostBack = true** for each radio button. Set **only one** radioButton as checked = true. I can see your code has both checked. Something like this...

The aspx page:

```
<asp:RadioButton id="radioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="btnGrp" Text="Button 1" AutoPostBack="true" Checked="true" OnCheckedChanged="radioButton1_CheckedChanged"></asp:RadioButton>

<asp:RadioButton id="radioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="btnGrp" Text="Button 2" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="radioButton2_CheckedChanged"></asp:RadioButton>
```

The code-behind (aspx.cs) page:

```
protected void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your code here
    }

protected void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your code here
    }
```

Hope this helps!